# Why is the parents field in Google Drive API an array?

Tags: google-drive-api

Perhaps this is irrelevant other than to appease my OCD, but why does the parent field in the Google Drive api (I'm using v3, but I believe it was the same in v2, too) return an array? Is there ever a situation where there would be multiple parents for a file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question, because many people make the mistake of thinking that a parent folder is some sort of container. It isn't. In GDrive you should think of parents (aka folders) as labels. It works pretty much the same way as GMail, ie. an individual email can have many labels.

Comment: yes, I guess that's true... it brings it in line with other Google services like GMail,etc. Thank you. Great response.